# Simplified way to handle one-to-many relationship updates in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'd been doing some research looking for a way to simplify the code to update a one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework, there are plenty of similar questions regarding how to update a one-to-many relationships but I couldn't find any simple solution.

Assuming I have the following model classes:

```
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
           .HasOptional(b => b.Author)
           .WithMany(v => v.Books)
           .HasForeignKey(s => s.AuthorId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

...
```

And considering a disconnected scenario where I want to:

- Add new Books to the collection
- Remove Books from the collection
- Modify exisitng Books of the collection

My first approach was to clear the author's book collection and set again with a new one:

```
var author = authorRepository.GetAuthor(authorId);
author.Books.Clear();
author.Books = updatedBooksCollection;
authorRepository.UpdateAuthor(author);
```

So, this approach works but it creates **orphan records** in the database.

One way to solve this is with an **Identifying Relationship**:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    ...
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Author")]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine when I clear the collection and set a new one **BUT I have to change my table schema adding a composite key**.

After researching a while I found this article (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) which explains clearly how to manage one-to-many relationship updates in a disconnected scenario like this.

I added this method to my repository class:

```
private void UpdateBooks(IEnumerable<Book> existingBooks, IEnumerable<Book> updatedBooks)
{
    var addedBooks = updatedBooks.Except(existingBooks, x => x.BookId);

        var deletedBooks = existingBooks.Except(updatedBooks, x => x.BookId);

        var modifiedBooks = updatedBooks.Except(addedBooks, x => x.BookId);

        addedBooks.ToList<Book>().ForEach(x => UnitOfWork.Context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Added);

        deletedBooks.ToList<Book>().ForEach(x => UnitOfWork.Context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var book in modifiedBooks)
        {
            var existingBook = UnitOfWork.Context.Set<Book>().Find(book.BookId);

            if (existingBook != null)
            {
                var contextBook = UnitOfWork.Context.Entry(existingBook);
                contextBook.CurrentValues.SetValues(book);
            }
        }

    UnitOfWork.Context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

And this works fine, but it seems a lot of code just to handle something trivial as an update of a collection, I don't want to do this for each collection I have in my model when I want to update it.

**My question is: Is there a simplified way to handle one-to-many relationship updates in Entity Framework without changing the table schema, I mean without adding a Identifying Relationship?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you had is fine with a small change.

```
var author = authorRepository.GetAuthor(authorId);
//author.Books.Clear();
//author.Books.ToList().ForEach(b => bookRepository.RemoveBook(b)); (Option 1)
context.Books.RemoveRange(author.Books); // (Option 2)
author.Books = updatedBooksCollection;
authorRepository.UpdateAuthor(author);
```

Clearing the collection is causing your orphan records because `Clear` only removes the author's FK reference from the book. When the reference is cleared the FK is set as null.

Comment: Ok, this seems a good approach but I have a couple of concerns:
**1.** I don't want to be calling the repository for each book: what happens if I have hundreds of items? Is that performant?
**2.** I'm not sure this is transactional: I'm calling the SaveChanges() for each book I remove and then updating the Author.

Comment: I've added another way to remove the author's books. Generally I write my repo methods in two ways. Ones that only act on the EF object graph and ones that additionally save those changes. The most performant way to do bulk deletes is to not use EF. You will just have to measure your performance with this to see if it's good enough for the sets you are working with.

Comment: Yes, I like this solution. Maybe a better way could be to put the **context.Books.RemoveRange(author.Books);** inside the AuthorRepository so that I only call **SaveChanges()** once.

Comment: It's a bit of a balance act. If you're doing bulk commands then calling `SaveChanges` too often is slow but calling it too few (or just once) can also be slow. I always profile the code against several datasets to get a good handle on what works best.

Comment: Thanks @Shoe! good advice, I should always make some performance measurements before deciding for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, although I accepted @Shoe's answer, I found another simple and reusable way to handle this.
I decided to use a generic method in my BaseRepository so I can reuse it for all the other collections by just calling:

```
UpdateRelatedEntityCollection<Book>(existingBooks, updatedBooks);
```

This is the refactored code:

**BaseRepository** class:

```
public void UpdateRelatedEntityCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> existingEntities, IEnumerable<T> updatedEntities) where T : BaseRelatedEntity
    {
        var addedEntities = updatedEntities.Except(existingEntities, x => x.Id);

        var deletedEntities = existingEntities.Except(updatedEntities, x => x.Id);

        var modifiedEntities = updatedEntities.Except(addedEntities, x => x.Id);

        addedEntities.ToList<T>().ForEach(x => UnitOfWork.Context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Added);

        deletedEntities.ToList<T>().ForEach(x => UnitOfWork.Context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var entity in modifiedEntities)
        {
            var existingEntity = UnitOfWork.Context.Set<T>().Find(entity.Id);

            if (existingEntity != null)
            {
                var contextEntry = UnitOfWork.Context.Entry(existingEntity);
                contextEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            }
        }
    }
```

**AuthorRepository** class:

```
   public void UpdateBooks(int id, List<Book> updatedBooks)
    {
        var author = GetAuthorById(id);
        var existingBooks = author.Books.ToList();

        UpdateRelatedEntityCollection<Book>(existingBooks, updatedBooks);

        UnitOfWork.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Not sure if this is the best way to manage one-to-many relationship updates in Entity Framework but I find it useful for not duplicating code.